# "The application will not be able to retrieve notifications. push Service :The Sender account is not recognized"

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have followed every step mentioned on IBM MobileFirst Platform Push Notification tutorial, but unfortunately it doesn't work it on my device.

I am getting this error:

> Failed registering for push notifications. The applicationwill not be
>   able to revieve notifications. pUsh Service :The Sender account is not
>   recognized.

Comment: Please add an example of how you have done this. It will aid people in guiding you to a solution.

Comment: Android? iOS? Worklight version? Full steps you've  followed? Your project setup?

Comment: Tried running the sample code provided by ibm worklight [https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/]  , have changed the push sender key and sender id with the ones i created with my google account. When i run the app on my device, it throws the error

Comment: Worklight version is 6.3 , I tried running on android

Comment: How did you create your account in the GCM console? What did you put as GCM key and SenderId? Did you create a Browser or Server key? I suspect your values are incorrect (as the error message denotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have likely incorrectly created your [GCM account](https://cloud.google.com/console).

1. Create a new project
2. After creating a new project, under **API Project > Overview** you will find your *Project Number*. This is your **senderId** value
3. Under **API Project > API & Auth > APIs**, make sure you've enabled "Google Cloud Messaging for Android"
4. Under **API Project > API and Auth > Credentials > Public API access***, make sure you've created a *Browser* key. This is your **GCM Key** value

In application-descriptor.xml,

- Enter the GCM Key from above
- Enter the senderId from above

Comment: How to simulate push notification if i have uploaded this app to my worklight 6.3 server?

Comment: Read the tutorial. It details exactly that.

Comment: I have uploaded the adapter and the wlapp files to my server and when i tried simulating using the PushBackend.jar file it takes "localhost" as the server url and not the actual server url. How do i set my worklight server url so as to simulate it.

Comment: Right-click the adapter folder and select to "invoke procedure". Enter the username and message, for example: "idan", "test message".

Comment: You also have the jar's source. You can modify it to your needs.

Comment: I have created a worklight environment on my server(server02.*********.com)  with context root as worklight_1 and have uploaded my adapter to that server (adapter file), the invoke procedure works only with the local server right?(it takes localhost right?). Just need to know how to simulate that?

Comment: I told you. Read above.